# What are they likely to ask?

Tags: religion

Not sure if this is appropriate to this site, but here's the scenario...

The chief deity creates forms and creates life (including the sentients) in the world
They then go on to create 3 more deities, 1 to care for each of the sentient species.
The care taker of one of the deities goes and talks to the "first man" and "first woman".

The first people have no knowledge of the world or this entity. It comes down and tells them that it who it's name and that it is the care taker of all the land.

The situation of the people is that they came into the world 3 days ago, have not eaten since they've existed. They have an instinct that says they need to eat, but they have no knowledge or understanding of how. The language that they know was magiced into them. Their apparent age is 20. They do posess magical abilities but they don't know about this or how to use it. Their environment is in a forest, by a river. They may have come across some animals but not many. They may have tried to eat some plants but nothing that would have sustained them. They have drank water. They have no weapons or clothes or anything like that. In terms of "species" they are esentially modern humans. Not any other less primitive homonid. They're very much like Adam and Eve, Modern humans pre-knowledge.

My question is, what are some questions that these people are likely ask it?

I'm having a hard time coming up with questions because I know everything about the world already and I am not a normal type of person ^.^ so my thinking process is far skewed from this scenario and putting myself in the head of these people.

So what are question that you are likely to ask in this scenario if you were in the position of the "first people"?

Comment: I do not think this question fits here. It is too story based. [Read about it here, you will get idea what to do next](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3300/49)

Comment: @PavelJanicek Well I'm asking what questions likely will be asked, not what they would or will ask. Obviously I'll be answering that ^.^ So according to that I think it may fit...

Comment: Such deity would probably get the same kind of question that *Deep Thought* got in *Hitchiker's Guide to the Galaxy*.

Comment: What are the limitations? Should those humans be believably similar to modern people / prehistoric people / Adam and Eve? They seem to already know the language; do they know anything else?

Comment: @Roux I edited the question, hope that description of their situation helps.

Comment: The first thing I would ask is... "Are Gods edible?"

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that these things are part of world building. Worlds are defined by their mythology and mythology is done through story telling either of factual events or morality tales as such to build a world you must form stories which is a different topic than writing. That's not only how the real world does it, but it's also how the writers known for world building do it, so trying to make this distinction of "too story based" is a mistake at best.

Answer (score 3):

Two people come into existence and then meet a god. They probably are going to have a little bit of an existential crisis and ask the stereotypical questions.
“What are we?”
“What is our purpose?”
“Why were we made?”
“Are we your slave, your entertainment? You said you were our ‘care taker’ are we your punishment?”

After they get conferrable talking to the deity they might start asking “oddball” questions like…
“What’s mine? Why can’t I have more?”
“Do I have to marry this other person? Can you make me another one instead?”
“Why do we have bellybuttons?”

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the main issue is that they should have no knowledge to back up their language.

For example, imagine a language that's almost unfamiliar to you - for example, the readings of chemical notations. Imagine they were magicked into you, so, when you think of water, "dihydrogen monoxide" automatically comes to your mind.
Also, you know a lot of other fancy words, like "methylamine" or "lithium hydride", but you  still don't know what these things are, if you have never ever encountered them.

For your people, "slavery", "punishment" or "marriage" should also mean nothing. Otherwise, if the meaning of every word is also magicked into them, they should know what is "methylamine", or "DNA" or "viruses". But then they would know all the things that modern English have named.

So, they can only name what they've seen in 3 days, which is not much:

- Who are you? Are there others?
- So you're a helper? Help us, we're hungry. How to get food? How to get more food?
- Also, we're hurt, how to fix it?
- (seeing magic) How can you do magic? Can we do it? How?
- Why the animals are running? Can we catch them? Why the skies are blue? By the way, what are "viruses"?

...basically, well, the same kind of questions that children ask.

Comment: Should be "dihydrogen monoxide", not "hydrogen dioxide".

Answer (score 0):

Who are you? Can you help me I can't find anything to eat? This should be the first questions they wold ask after trying for 3 days to find something to eat.  Once to immediate survival is taken care of they can ask the more deeper questions Who Am I, who are you, I am I here and so on. But before they got to the deeper questions they probably ask a million more questions about how their world works. They don't even know what is food and what isn't so they probably would ask a lot of stupid questions like one of those tall things coming up from the ground (trees). Do those green things ever get tired of grabbing on to them (leaves). How do the trees eat without a mouth? Stuff like that

Comment: I put in that they have drank water ^.^ Not eatting for 3 days won't hurt you. You can survive without eating for around 3 weeks if I remember right.

Comment: @Durakken if they know that they need to drink why would they not know that they need to eat?

Comment: @Durakken okay I get it it's not a matter of not knowing that they need to eat it's not knowing what they can and cannot eat. OK I get I will edit my answer shortly.

Comment: They don't know they need to. They get a feeling of hunger or thirst and try things... Water makes this thirst feeling go away and some of the hunger feeling, but they don't know why or how. And catching, killing, and preparing isn't a thing I'd think of to do. ^.^